# How to increment an Integer-lvalue

Tags: java, dictionary, integer

I have a map from type

```
Map<Character, Integer> tmp;
```

and at some point in my code, I do the following:

```
if(tmp.containsKey(key))
    tmp.put(key, tmp.get(key)+1)
```

In the second line, I would prefer to just do something like

```
    tmp.get(key)++;
```

which I expected to work, since I should get a reference to the Integer Object from the get-call. But it doesn't, and Integer doesn't seem to have an update function apart from the int-syntax. Is there no way around the first construct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `Integer` class objects are immutable, you can't modify it. You've to put the result back into the map. One option is to use mutable value like [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html):

```
Map<Character, AtomicInteger> tmp;
tmp.get(ch).incrementAndGet();
```

Answer (score 4):

Primitives don't work with generics, so you have to use `Integer` objects instead of `int` values.

You can't use this

```
tmp.get(key)++;
```

because that gets translated into something like

```
Integer value = tmp.get(key);
int intValue = value.intValue();
value = Integer.valueOf(intValue += 1); // different Integer reference now stored in value
```

So you see, the reference in `tmp` remains the same.

The way you are currently doing it is correct. Or do what [Rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22793174/438154) is suggesting with a class that wraps the increment operation, like `AtomicInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but not with an Integer wrapper class. Wrapper objects are immutable, so you're actually getting a new reference there. Consider this code,

```
Integer i = 1;
Integer j = i;
System.out.printf("i=%d, j=%d, i == j is %b\n", i, j, i == j);
++i;
System.out.printf("i=%d, j=%d, i == j is %b\n", i, j, i == j);
```

You will notice that the increment of `i` has no effect on `j`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet%28%29) which has increment and decrement functions.

```
if(tmp.containsKey(key))
    tmp.get(key).incrementAndGet();
```